# App crashes only after second execution only in Release configuration

Tags: iphone, release, core-plot

i know this is probably not an easy question to answer, as it's hard to describe on my hand.
I have an app that runs without problems on the device in Debug Configuration (also multiple times).

Once I put it into Release Configuration (which I need before publishing?), the app starts without problems and I can proceed to the next page, where I show an [core-plot](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/) graph. BUT only if I run it from xcode. As soon as I end the App and start it again, it opens without problems, but on the next page, it crashes. Now I don't have anything to debug other than the crash report:

```
  Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xcf10000a
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000026f2 objc_msgSend + 14
1   StandbyCheck                    0x0001fbea -[CPXYTheme newGraph] (CPXYTheme.m:36)
2   StandbyCheck                    0x00007c06 -[SCGraphCell initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:] (SCGraphCell.m:28)
3   StandbyCheck                    0x00076b4a -[TTTableViewDataSource tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (TTTableViewDataSource.m:128)
4   UIKit                           0x0007797a -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 514
5   UIKit                           0x000776b0 -[UITableView(UITableViewInternal) _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 28
6   UIKit                           0x00037e78 -[UITableView(_UITableViewPrivate) _updateVisibleCellsNow] + 940
7   UIKit                           0x000367d4 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 176
8   StandbyCheck                    0x000734b8 -[TTTableView layoutSubviews] (TTTableView.m:226)
```

[...]

Now, can someone point in any direction? What are the differences in Debug/Release Modes? How could I possibly debug this failure?

I've been searching for hours now, please help me :(
Thanks,
Dennis

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, there's nothing in that line of `CPXYTheme.m` that would cause a crash. Particularly as it's a call to `self`, with an argument that was constructed in the method where the crash occurs. OK, so that leaves the obvious possibility of a concurrency problem - particularly as the crash occurs only in some configurations and not all the time. What are you doing on other threads that might affect the lifetime of your `CPXYTheme` object, or the `SCGraphCell`, or any object that "owns" them (the table view data source, view controller and so on)?